# how to plot marginal effect with 2SLS model

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a question about possible package in R that would allow me to plot marginal effect of regression model when my model is 2SLS/IV model. I am including a quadratic term in my regression model, and I would need to plot the marginal effect graph to truly interpret the effect of the regressors. I have been using ggpredict and ggplot to plot marginal effect on OLS model with quadratic/interaction terms.

Comment: Unfortunately, package requests are off-topic on the site.

Comment: So you said that you already used `ggpredict()`, and this was not sufficient?